# Multiple Service Providers using Spring saml

Tags: single-sign-on, multi-tenant, saml-2.0, spring-saml, adfs3.0

I have multiple web applications in different tomcat servers. Now I have to implement SSO with ADFS across all applications. I am not clear about the approach.

AS POC I have used Spring saml to achieve SSO with ADFS in one web application. Can we use the POC application as the service provider for all other business application? If Yes, As this SSO is browser based, how other applications can retrieve claims from one service provider. Or do we need to use spring saml in all applications one by one? This option is a herculean task as I have to make changes (inclusion of necessary jars and code) in all applications. I read about multi-tenancy, but could not get anything.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to modify all your applications. In a standard SAML deployment, each application is a separate Service Provider.